# Would this Point Buy house rule for Maid character creation work at all?

Tags: character-creation, house-rules, balance, maid

Recently we've started a maid game here on the stack and we have a huge disparity of stats between the players, one of them has barely average stats, while some of the other players are pushing fours and sixes in abilities because of great rolls during generation. We have found that the standard rule that characters with good stats get fewer maid powers is insufficient.

Would a point buy system work in Maid RPG while still being able to attain the same level of play in Maid games? Using the favor base presented in the handbook I've come up with the following figures for point buy statistics. The standard array in Maid would be 1,1,2,2,3,3 or you could buy points at the following costs, with 200 starting favor:

0: 0 points
1: 10 points
2: 30 points
3: 60 points
4: 100 points

With the stipulation that any favor points not used during point buy are lost. Does a system like this function properly in the Maid system provided the Maid characteristics (Boyish, Sexy, Lolita, Pure, etc.) were rolled after (and only after) a character has distributed their points as they wish?

Comment: It's quite difficult to answer that question... While there can be an answer to "Have you successfully used a point-based creation system in Maid RPG?", it is more difficult to answer "Would this houserule work?"

Comment: "Does a system like this function properly?" is the same as "Would this rule work?". It's just worded differently.

Comment: @Cristol.GdM Asking whether house rules would work is fine. Answers about house rules are expected to be from experience though, so this might just go without decent answers for a long time, until a site member tries it and can report its functionality (or lack thereof) from experience.

Answer (score 7):

While a point-buy option is certainly a possibility in any RPG, Maid isn't one that lends itself well to it. The rules in general focus fairly heavily on randomization and character-impermanence. Chaos is meant to be part of the fun. Naturally, you *can* run a more "serious" game (relatively speaking), but keep in mind what the game is based around - anime featuring zany antics featuring outrageous, sometimes nonsensical characters. Point buy will come at a thematic cost, producing more "sane" and "normal" characters.

If you haven't already, take a look at some of the optional rules for ways to give players a bit more options when it customization and making trade-offs to better focus their abilities before changing how characters are generated outright.